# How to dynamically push down a second-row div based on the height of the child in the first row div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

is it possible for a child inside a div to push down other divs outside based on its own height?

Given this simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="main-section">
        <div class="main-form">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget
          sollicitudin urna. Duis congue mattis risus nec volutpat. Cras ut
          risus et diam luctus consectetur. Phasellus aliquam dui nec vehicula
          convallis. Donec sit amet nunc lacus. Praesent eget elit commodo,
          ultricies felis non, tristique ex.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about-section">Hello World</div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have this CSS here, there are basically two divs (main-section and about-section) and the main-form is inside the main-section:

```
.main-section {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;

  /* display: table; solution 1*/

  /* overflow: auto; solution 2, it cuts off the yellow div, which is not the desired outcome */
}

.main-form {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 120px;
  min-height: 180px;

  /* display: table-col; solution 1*/
}

.about-section {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The height of the parent `.main-section` should be fixed at 100px.

The height of the child `.main-form` **varies depending on the length of the text on it**, but should have a min-height of 180px.
The width of the `.main-form` should be fixed at 120px.

I have tried changing the `overflow` property of the parent but it cuts off the child element.
I have also tried using the `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-col` on the child, but this solution adjusts the height of the parent element.

Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wave-29f5f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Is there a way to do this?

Basically what I wanted to achieve looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float and clear can do the job:

```css
.main-section {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.main-form {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 120px;
  float:left; /* here */
  min-height: 180px;
}

.about-section {
  background-color: blue;
  clear:left; /* and here */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="main-form">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget sollicitudin urna. Duis congue mattis risus nec volutpat. Cras ut risus et diam luctus consectetur. Phasellus aliquam dui nec vehicula convallis. Donec sit amet nunc lacus. Praesent eget
    elit commodo, ultricies felis non, tristique ex.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="about-section">Hello World</div>
```